# Make one line of border curved

Tags: css

[image: Preview]

How can I make one line of border(**not corner, not `border-radius`**) curved like in the preview? Some questions before used `transform: rotate`, but that way is impossible to make the top part round. Currently my css is `border-radius: 100px 100px 0px 0px`, so the top part is like the preview. But I cannot find how to make the bottom part

Comment: Have you tried doing it with a svg ? I know it's possible, but i wont be able to write it :/

Comment: try something alike : `div {
 border-radius: 60%  / 90% 90%  25% 25% ;
  border:solid;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
}`  dem https://jsbin.com/jiyuposixe/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to nest an inner div inside an outer div and apply a different size and border -radius on the inner one - but make the out one have overflow- hidden.This will allow you to have different curves on the top and the bottom - but I agree with the suggestion that you should use an SVG for this.

```css
.outer {
  height: 800px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}


.inner {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: visible;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
  position: relative; 
  top: -58.1%;
  left: -50px
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```